# jquerymobile how to make customized filter?

Tags: jquery-mobile

i have the list view with filter like this :

```
   <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li>Week 01</li>
            <li>Week 02</li>
            <li>Week 03</li>
            <li>Week 04</li>
            <li>Week 05</li>
            <li>Week 06</li>
            <li>Week 07</li>
            <li>Week 08</li>
            <li>Week 09</li>
            <li>Week 10</li>
        </ul>
```

in the filter bar, i can able to get the result if i search by "week 01" or "1". it show the result.

but my requirement is, if the user types like "01-05", then the filter need to show the content of "01" to "05". ( that means it need to show from 1 to 5 of the list). in this case how can i customize the filter to achieve this?

Any one help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to define filter function with property `$.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterCallback` during `mobileinit` event, or after you have created the listview, with `$("#mylist").listview('option', 'filterCallback', yourFilterFunction)`. The filter function has the format `function( text, searchValue )`, where `text` is the current li element, and `searchValue` is the text you wrote in the filter input.

You will find this information and more in the [jQueryMobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html), in the section "Search filter".